# Bottom alignment of widgets inside ui-grid blocks

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am using the JQM grids for grouping and dividing content.
Is there a way to align the content to the bottom of the `ui-grid-a` or `ui-grid-b`?
I tried many of the proposed solutions to make the `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b` divs  the same height, but none of them played nicely together with the JQM grid system.

Below is an example with two `flipswitch` widgets which have labels of different text lenght. How can I keep the widgets always vertical aligned? (Pure CSS but w/out Flex appreciated)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
    <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch with more caption text:</label>
    <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
    <label for="flip-checkbox-2">Flipswitch 2:</label>
    <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-2" id="flip-checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't fully understand why, setting the `block` width to 49% instead of 50% does the job:

```css
/* JQM Better alignment for grids with long heading text */
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a align-widgets">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch with more caption text:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-2">Flipswitch 2:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-2" id="flip-checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:table` on the parent and `display:table-cell` for the children :

```css
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets{
  display: table;
}
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-b {
  display: table-cell;  
  float: none;  
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a align-widgets">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch with more caption text:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-2">Flipswitch 2:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-2" id="flip-checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do You have an explanation why my solution works when I set the block width at 49%?

Answer (score 0):

In reply to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251335/9217760):

> Though I can't fully understand why, setting the block width to 49%
>   instead of 50% does the job

**Check these out:**

> a series of `inline-block` elements formatted like you normally format
>   HTML will have spaces in between them

— [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) by CSS-TRICKS

> One problem that arrises when you use `inline-block` is that whitespace
>   in HTML becomes visual space on screen.

— [Remove Whitespace Between Inline-Block Elements](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) by David Walsh

So setting the `display` of the `.ui-block-a` and `.ui-block-b` to `inline-block` gives you the ability to vertically-align the elements at the bottom (of its parent/container) — by setting their `vertical-align` to `bottom`.

However, setting their `width` to `50%` will push the `.ui-block-b` down below the `.ui-block-a` because of the *(white)space between the elements*, in the HTML code:

```
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
```

There are several ways you can choose from in order to fix that issue:

***Remove the spaces***

```
</div><div class="ui-block-b">
```

Or use the "comment trick" (I used this in the Code Snippet):

```
</div><!--
--><div class="ui-block-b">
```

**Apply a *Negative Margin* on the `inline-block` elements**

```
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

**Use *`font-size: 0`* on the parent**

```
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets {
  font-size: 0; /* Removes the `inline-block` gaps. */
}

.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

For more details, see:

- [css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
- [davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

```css
/* JQM Better alignment for grids with long heading text */
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a.align-widgets>.ui-block-b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="ui-grid-a align-widgets">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch with more caption text:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div><!--
          This comment block removes the `inline-block` gaps, allowing you to use
          a 50% width on `.ui-block-a` and `.ui-block-b`.
        --><div class="ui-block-b">
          <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a">
            <label for="flip-checkbox-2">Flipswitch 2:</label>
            <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-2" id="flip-checkbox-2" type="checkbox">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```